# ASP.NET MVC set value of a globally accessible variable permanently

Tags: asp.net-mvc, save, global-variables

I am writing an application in ASP.NET MVC with three type of users: Student, Staff and Admin.

Students must be able to select and apply for Programs that are set by the Admin. Programs are separated in Terms : Summer, Autumn and Spring which is saved in a database field in the Programs Table called "term".

I want for the admin to be able to set the term, so when users(students and staff) log in, they can only view programs available only for that term. The thing is i cannot save it in a database as my database has Tables such as StaffProfile (retrieves the usernames and passwords of the Admin and the Staff) and Programs(contains information for each program) and a new table only for the term would not be an ideal solution.

I want to save the term variable somewhere, that can be accessed globally and not be destroyed when the application ends.

Maybe this has a simple solution i cannot see.I have considered ApplicationState but i am not sure if this is the way to go.
Any ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding of your question. You can store global variable in web.config or global.asax file. you can also use session. you have another option by static declaring static class. like

```
public static class GlobalVariables
{
    // readonly variable
    public static string Foo
    {
        get
        {
            return "foo";
        }
    }

    // read-write variable
    public static string Bar
    {
        get
        {
            return HttpContext.Current.Application["Bar"] as string;
        }
        set
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Application["Bar"] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

please correct me If I am wrong.

Comment: it works perfectly but i have one question. As i have not yet published my application, when i restart it in Visual Studio, the value is removed. My question is, if i publish it, will the value be saved as long as the application is up and running?